# Debian server hangs when bridge is enabled

Tags: networking, debian, xen

Alright so basically my interfaces file looks like this.
Now this works if I bring the interface down and up again once linux has booted. But if I attempt to restart it gets stuck loading the network interfaces and says something like 
"waiting for to xenbr0 to ready (MAXWAIT 32 seconds).

Now of course it doesn't actually ever get past this so I'm kind of stumped. I can remove the bridge and it boots fine.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.3
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        dns-domain lan
        dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 127.0.0.1
auto xenbr0
iface xenbr0 inet static
       address 192.168.1.2
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       broadcast 192.168.1.255
       gateway 192.168.1.1
       dns-domain lan
       dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 127.0.0.01
       bridge_ports eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

can u change to this

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet manual

and remove other entries for eth0, keeping xenbr0 with out changing and then restart network.